# HTML/CSS Moving element somewhere else

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a feeling my question has a simple answer but I'm having a difficult time wording it without finding a relevant answer.  I wish to move a button, using CSS, below another button but cannot place that element below it in HTML.  Below is a simplified version of the code I'm working with to illustrate my problem:

```
<form class="form1">
   <!-- other input elements -->
   <button class="button1"></button>
</form>
<form class="form2">
   <button class="button2"></button>
</form>
```

"form1" must stay above "form2" but I wish to move "button1" below "button2".  Can this be done with CSS?  If it helps, I am using Bootstrap 4.

Edit: Thank you for the responses!  I should have been more clear and I have updated my code above which I hope helps.  There are some other input elements within "form1" that need to appear above "form2".  Of course, as-is, this is the case.  However, I wish to move not form1 below form2, but only button1 below button2.  All the other elements within form1 I wish to stay above form2.

Comment: you can use `position:absolute` css property for "button1" to move it anywhere without affecting other elements

Comment: you dont want to add or change the html?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) what is the problem you are actually trying to solve? Minimal examples are good, but there is such a thing as too minimal if important context is left out.

Comment: @JonP Yes, you are indeed right.  Full context: I have a form that includes a list with corresponding checkboxes and a button that deletes those items that are checked.  Below that form is another form that that has an input which allows users to add something and a button to confirm adding that input.  Aesthetically, having the delete button above the input looks odd, and I was trying to move the delete button below the input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also achieve this by using the CSS position:

```css
div {position: relative}
.form1 {position: absolute;margin-top: 22px;}
.form2 {position: absolute}
```

```html
<div>
  <form class="form1">
   <button class="button1">button1</button>
</form>
<form class="form2">
   <button class="button2">button2</button>
</form><div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in light of the edit I made in my post?  button1 would not be a sister element to button2 since both are child elements of their respective forms, I'm having a difficult time to find CSS properties that are relevant to me as a result

Comment: Just try to make the parent position relative and child position absolute and then apply margin/top/left/right/bottom etc. to adjust the position of child elements.

Comment: @JerilonFenton - if it works for you, don't forget to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox with the [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property to change their display order visually without touching the HTML structure:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.form2 {
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <form class="form1">
     <button class="button1">Button 1</button>
  </form>
  <form class="form2">
     <button class="button2">Button 2</button>
  </form>
  <form class="form3">
     <button class="button3">Button 3</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a solution using bootstrap 4, which you have already use.

I have used Bootstrap 4 Grid order classes for this solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 order-2">
                    <form class="form1 ">
                        <button class="button1">Button 1</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 order-1">
                    <form class="form2 ">
                    <button class="button2">Button 2</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**flexbox** can change the visual order of any elements using the ***order*** property.

**CSS**

```
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.wrap div {
  padding: 1em;
}
#first {
  background: #64703b;
  order: 2
}
#last {
  background: #ee0000;
  order: 1
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">  
<form class="form1" ID="first">
   <button class="button1">button1</button>
</form>
<form class="form2" ID="last">
   <button class="button2">button2</button>
</form>
</div>
```